# What is the easiest way to fix multiple dead links a article Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

As I've started editing Wikipedia I've noticed that some older articles will have many dead links with no archived url attached.

What is the best way to handle this besides manually finding the archived url and editing each reference?

Is there a tag I can put on the page so a bot will fix it or is there some sort of widget to automatically do this?

All advice appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InternetArchiveBot](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/InternetArchiveBot) for example has a bunch of link rot related services.